# Factor $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)-24$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Factor $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)-24$.

**My attempt**:I did it a long and boring way:

$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)-24=x(x^3+10x^2+35x+50)$

After that I solved the equation $x^3+10x^2+35x+50=0$
and found the integer solution $-5$
and I divided the polynomial to $x+5$ and got the answer $x^2+5x+10$ and factored it like this:

$x(x+5)(x^2+5x+10)$

I want an easier way to solve it; which way would you recommend?

Comment: If you recognise $24=1\times 2 \times 3 \times 4$ then $x=0$ clearly gives a zero so $x$ is a factor.  But clearly you also have $24 = (-4)\times (-3)\times (-2)\times (-1)$ so $x=-5$ also gives a zero and $x+5$ is another factor

Comment: often on this site, the product of four consecutive numbers is one less than a square; this is reflected in an explicit factorization (product of two quadratics), worth going through yourself. Thus, this question is a squared polynomial minus $5^2.$ The first item is the reason $4! + 1$ and $5! + 1$ are squares.

Comment: It's pretty clear immediately that $x=0$ and $x=-5$ are roots, because $24=4!=1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 = (-4)\cdot (-3)\cdot (-2)\cdot (-1)$.  So $x$ and $x+5$ will be factors.  Multiplying it out (the long and boring way) and then dividing by those known factors seems like the easiest approach.

Comment: @Henry is there any way without calculating the roots?

Comment: For $7! + 1,$ necessary to write $7! = 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10,$ and confirm same factorization, to see it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x=0$ and $x=-5$ are roots of the given equation,
$$ (x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)-24 = x(x+5)\cdot q(x) \tag{1} $$
where $q(x)$ is a monic second-degree polynomial. We may notice that, by De l'Hopital's rule,
$$ q(0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)-24}{x(x+5)}=\frac{24\,H_4}{5}=10 \tag{2}$$
and if $q(x)=x^2+Kx+10$, in order that the coefficient of $x^3$ is the same in both sides of $(1)$
$$ 1+2+3+4 = K+5 \tag{3} $$
i.e. $K=5$, has to hold.

Comment: What does $H_4$ denote?

Comment: @ShreyAryan: the fourth harmonic number, namely $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 3):

Since the polynomial is symmetric around $x+2.5$ let us set $y=x+2.5$.

Then
$$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)-24=(y-\frac{3}{2})(y-\frac{1}{2})(y+\frac{1}{2})(y+\frac{3}{2})-24\\
=(y^2-\frac{1}{4})(y^2-\frac{9}{4})-24=y^4-\frac{5}{2}y^2-\frac{375}{16}=(y^2+\frac{15}{4})(y^2-\frac{25}{4})
$$

Comment: and $y^2-\frac{25}{4}=y^2 - \left( \frac52\right)^2 = \left( y-\frac52\right)\left( y+\frac52\right)$

Comment: @Henry I left it there because factoring quadratics should be easy, even if they were not difference of squares ;)

Answer (score 0):

$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4) - 24 =(x^2 +5x +4)(x^2+5x+6) -24=Y$

Let $x^2+5x=t$.

So,  $Y=(t+4)(t+6) - 24 = t^2+10t=t(t+10)$
Implying, $Y=(x^2+5x)(x^2+5x+10)=x(x+5)(x^2+5x+10)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! In the future please format your answer using MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference